# Script which takes a file from user, encode it in base64 and forward the file in email

Tags: email, php

I am trying to create a script which takes file from the user, encode it in base64 and then forward it to an email as attachment with encoded file.

This is the code till now :

Client side :

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
</form>
```

PHP Script (send.php)

```
<?php
$uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
$handle = fopen($uploaded_file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content1 = base64_encode($content);
$my_file = "'$encoded_file' . '_encoded' . '.html'";
$handle1 = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle1, $content1);
$from="tes@gmail.com";
$to="myemail@gmail.com"
$subject="New file";
$message="you got a new file";
mail($from,$to,$subject,$message);
unlink($my_file);
?>
```

I don't know how to attach $myfile in the email.

Comment: Did You tried Google before asking here? Google is full of examples on how to attach file to the email body even with pure `mail()` function...

Comment: This is a great source of examples: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: Yep i did, but most of them used chunk_split, something like this, i didn't understand what's the use of the same.I also visited the link you gave, but same thing in the same.  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));

Comment: Then open another question asking "what does `chunk_split()` do?". Or better yet put some effort into your work and read the manual page describing [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php), it works similarly to [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using any external mail libraries such as PEAR::SMTP or Swift then creating the attachments is not a simple thing.

You will have to check the mail standards they instruct on how to separate the headers from the message content and the message content from the attachments.

The separator is `\r\n` and each section must be preceded by a separator.

Check this link out: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

And my code example:

```
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = implode("\r\n",
    array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'From: Address <address@example.com>',
        'Reply-To: Address <address@example.com>',
        'Cc: Address <address@example.com>',
        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;',
        '    boundary="'.$uid.'"',
        '',
        '--'.$uid,
        'Content-Type: text/plain;',
        '    charset="us-ascii"',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
        '',
        mb_convert_encoding(
            implode("\r\n",
                array_map('wordwrap',
                    array(
                        'Hello,',
                        '',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla laoreet varius augue non pretium. Nullam dignissim iaculis velit, ut cursus neque mollis et. Fusce faucibus dictum nunc, sit amet cursus tellus aliquam ut. Praesent id libero orci, ut vehicula orci. Proin nulla sem, dapibus in lacinia vel, pharetra eget eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras rhoncus, enim sed mollis suscipit, sapien mauris suscipit mauris, nec placerat nisi sapien ac lectus. Sed vehicula faucibus iaculis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer placerat commodo nibh. Morbi sit amet augue vitae urna mattis pulvinar ac eget tellus. Donec mattis cursus posuere. Donec dolor velit, aliquam eu pretium vel, accumsan eu est. Proin at ante nisi, ut malesuada diam.',
                        '',
                        'Nulla ac urna lacus, in luctus ipsum. Nunc luctus risus non dui tincidunt in ultricies tellus rhoncus. Aliquam pellentesque vehicula adipiscing. Phasellus porttitor sodales quam et cursus. Pellentesque iaculis consectetur lorem, et consectetur sem tristique sed. Duis vehicula eleifend nisl, a semper augue lobortis cursus. Fusce ut ligula diam. Quisque fringilla sodales massa vitae rhoncus. Pellentesque a libero sed enim lacinia commodo quis et dolor. Praesent facilisis, orci nec lacinia ultrices, enim nunc imperdiet augue, at aliquet dolor augue nec nulla.',
                        '',
                        'Ut venenatis commodo pulvinar. Vestibulum quam odio, malesuada posuere porttitor facilisis, molestie vel risus. Mauris auctor fringilla ornare. Morbi eu libero orci, nec semper lorem. Quisque blandit, ante nec pharetra bibendum, felis felis tincidunt felis, sed mattis sapien lorem et risus. In sed interdum quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas vitae metus id purus ultrices fermentum. In dui eros, feugiat sit amet feugiat vel, accumsan vitae ligula. Nam at consectetur elit. Maecenas eget metus id nibh luctus mattis. Quisque mollis, sapien semper vulputate venenatis, purus arcu ornare orci, sit amet pellentesque enim ipsum non urna. Quisque at augue nec quam vehicula suscipit eu a dui. Morbi at molestie nunc. Mauris ultricies rutrum euismod. Sed non sem nisi. '
                    )
                )
            ),
            'iso-8859-1'
        ),
        '',
        '--'.$uid,
        'Content-Type: application/pdf;',
        '    name="file.pdf"',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',
        'Content-Disposition: attachment;',
        '    filename="file.pdf"',
        '',
        chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('file.pdf'))),
        '--'.$uid.'--'
    )
);
mail($contacts, 'Subject', '', $header);
```

Comment: Hey, its just for personal use. So i guess SMTP is not required. I can use PHP mailer for the reference. Files are sent through $headers ?

Comment: If it's for personal use meaning that you are trying to learn how the underlying software is doing it then you're right.

Comment: If it's for personal use meaning that you just want to send emails using it it's easier to use SMTP or Swift.

Comment: @shadyyx It's the first google result for the keywords 'email attachment php::mail'. Have some faith that you weren't the only one to get there or the first one.

Comment: Can you modify my code so that i know how is it doing the same ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I'm personally here to help people learn. I'll explain, I'll give examples, I'll spot mistakes in someone else's code. But I do not want to write code for others. I already do that professionally for my clients.

Comment: By modifying the code, you are also helping people to learn, nevermind different mindset. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body = preg_replace('/[\]/', '', $body);

$mail->SetFrom('tes@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("tes@gmail.com", "First Last");
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "John Doe");
$mail->Subject = "New File";
$mail->AltBody = "you got a new file";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);


$my_file = file_put_contents("tmp.html", base64_encode($content));
$mail->AddAttachment($my_file); // attachment


if (! $mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```